# Image src for 100+ images - iOS app size concern

Tags: javascript, android, ios, performance, ionic-framework

I have a simple app that I am making with Ionic and I can not figure out which route to take with the images. I have about 150 images that need to be ready and available quickly. They are small 200x200png files but I don't know if I should package them in my assets folder or put them online somewhere and use the url as src. These need to load quick as the images randomly spawn but I don't want my application to be heavy.

Comment: If they need to load quickly then you don't want to be downloading them over an unreliable cellular connection. Best to stick them in asset catalogs in this case. If your images are large you don't want to be downloading 150 large images anyway.

Comment: You could probably get away with putting those in the assets catalogue, but also consider hosting them on an image server and using SDWebImage to cache them to disk during the first application launch. They should persist between sessions

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use the `Fresco` library it's good to situations like yours.
See here:
http://frescolib.org/docs/getting-started.html